# Get next,previous post in 2 level categories in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, pagination

I have 2 level categories like this:

```
paintings 
    - car
    - cat
    - dog 
other
    - other1
    - other2
...
```

Now I've many posts in each sub-category.
My goal is get the next post and previous post from the current post in current main category.

For example : I've a post name : "a good car" in car category. Then I've a post name : "A big cat " in cat category . Then I've a post name : "a small dog " in dog category.

Now in the "a big cat" post , I'm trying to get the 'a small dog' post as next post and the 'a good car' as prev post.

I'm used:

```
codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post
```

and:

```
codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post
```

but they still can't get the right post for me.

If I try with:

```
get_previous_post( false, '' )
```

I will get the previous post but not in painting category.

Also If I try with:

```
get_previous_post( true, '' )
```

I will get only the previous post in the current category , not the painting category.

Comment: I also faced this problem. The best link I found for it is given below.
http://yondershore.com/paging-through-sub-category-posts/ I hope it will help :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I would be sure that your "cat" paintings belong to both the "cat" and "paintings" categories. By default, I believe, the WordPress PREV/NEXT functions will work the way you're explaining.

i would expect this to work for you, provided your items are included in both the sub and main categories:

```
<?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous in category', TRUE); ?>
```

More details:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_post_link and 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link

Comment: Thank for your answers, however if I have a other post from other category, then it will display in next post of the painting category.

Comment: I see, if you don't have it yet, you can filter the "other" category out by adding the "other" category ID: <?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous in category', TRUE, '13'); ?> (assumes the "other" category ID is 13)